# When implementing bind, why name the second parameter k?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, monads

```
instance Monad M where
    m >>= k = ...
```

Also is there a name for functions which are used as this second argument to bind?

Comment: I'd guess that `k` stands for something like "kontinue with the kontinuation `k`".

Comment: Thanks, so the second argument to bind is call a continuation. Which would make a lot of sense

Comment: What would you prefer to call it, and what are your reasons for that? In other words, does it actually matter?

Comment: I think it matters. Giving things names helps you calculate/reason about them, other people are better at naming than me, and I assumed they had already given it a name, so you should use that one if you want to be able to communicate

Comment: I name it various things depending on the definition, `pure`, `var`, `next`, `ret`, .. I don't like the *k* name

Comment: It actually does matter that a name not suggest more semantic content than actually exists. I wouldn't use a name stronger than `f` or `k` to represent a function argument that can do anything it wants as long as its type is valid. Choosing between them mostly comes down to taste

Answer (score 1):

Answered in the comments

> I'd guess that k stands for something like "kontinue with the kontinuation k

Comment: I left it in the comments, because right now, I don't have the time to elaborate how exactly it's related to what flavor of continuations, and [how it all fits together](https://blog.poisson.chat/posts/2019-10-27-continuation-submonads.html), I hoped that someone else could provide a less hand-wavy answer.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin cool, perhaps you could help phrase the question too.